# Python OOP init

Tags: python, oop, init, self

```
class Sequence:
    TranscriptionTable = {
        "A":"U",
        "T":"A",
        "C":"G",
        "G":"C"
    }
    def __init__(self, seqstring):
        self.seqstring = seqstring.upper()
    def transcription(self):
        tt = ""
        for x in self.seqstring:
            if x in 'ATGC':
                tt += self.TranscriptionTable[x]
        return tt

DangerousVirus = Sequence('atggagagccttgttcttggtgtcaa')

print(DangerousVirus.transcription())
```

Hi,

I just want some clarification as to how data flows through a class. For instance, is the data in () in DangerousVirus = Sequence('atggagagccttgttcttggtgtcaa') self or seqstring?

I'm confused as to how **init** can have 2 variables when theres only 1 in the (). Wouldnt that mean that only self contains the sequence and seqstring is empty?

Thanks for the help! (:

Comment: Have you read the [Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) section in the official tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

`self` is a reference to a Sequence which is being initialized. The data string is passed as `seqstring`. You can see this by adding a line to print it:

```
print(seqstring)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `__init__` method does indeed take two arguments, but once an instance is created the `self` argument is "bound" to the instance (`__init__` becomes a so called bound method of the instance), so you don't have to specify the instance itself anymore. If you call the  unbound `__init__` function from the class like this

```
Sequence.__init__(instance, seqstring)
```

you indeed have to specify the instance explicitly. The name `self` is just a convention, it could be anything in the definition. Take a look at the [tutorial section on instance methods](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects) where this is explained.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers have said, the `self` arg gets passed automatically to method calls. So you *must* include it as the first arg in the method definition, but you must *not* include it in the method call.

However, there's no need to define a class for this, a simple function is sufficient. And you can use the built-in [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) method to perform the transcription very efficiently. For large sequences, this is *much* faster than doing it with a Python loop as in your `transcription` method, since most of the work is done by compiled code, so it runs as fast as if it were written in C, not Python.

```
trans_table = str.maketrans('ATCG', 'UAGC')

def transcribe(seq):
    seq = seq.upper()
    return seq.translate(trans_table)

seq = 'atggagagccttgttcttggtgtcaa'
print(transcribe(seq))
```

**output**

```
UACCUCUCGGAACAAGAACCACAGUU
```

---

As mentioned in the docs, any chars that aren't in the translation table will remain unchanged in the output string. Eg,

```
print('abcdABCD'.translate(trans_table))
```

**output**

```
abcdUBGD
```